# How would one translate "jury duty" into Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin

I have jury duty today, and I'm trying to figure out how I might say that in Latin.

For the drawing of names it seems to me that *sortítió* is probably the best word.

For "jury," though, a few options strike me, one following the historical function and one following the language. In the Roman Republic, members of the jury were called *júdicés* ("judges") and the trial was presided over by a *præator urbánus* ("city magistrate," for want of a more exact term). We can see this term for jury members in the first sentence of *Pró Rosció Amerínó*:

> Credo ego vos, iudices, mirari, quid sit, quod, cum tot summi oratores hominesque nobilissimi sedeant, ego potissimum surrexerim, is, qui neque aetate neque ingenio neque auctoritate sim cum his, qui sedeant, comparandus.

So if we look to what the *function* of Roman *júdicés* was, then we get *júdicum sortítió*, and we'd call the judge, I guess, a *prætor*. This seems weird, given how exactly *júdex* translates into "judge."

If we let the modern judge be called *júdex* instead, though, what's left for the jury? It occurs to me that *cónsilium* is a possibility, again as evidenced by *Pró Sextó Amerínó*

> Qui ex civitate in senatum propter dignitatem, ex senatu in hoc **consilium** delecti estis propter severitatem, ab his hoc postulare homines sicarios atque gladiatores, non modo ut supplicia vitent, quae a vobis pro maleficiis suis metuere atque horrere debent, verum etiam ut spoliis ex hoc iudicio ornati auctique discedant?

I understand that to a certain extent the choice of *júdicum sortítió* and *cónsilií sortítió* is a matter of one's philosophy of translation. But is there one that living Latinists use? Or is there an even better choice (for either word) that just isn't occurring to me?

Comment: I just checked the [Magna Carta](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/magnacarta.html). Alas, I don't think it has a word for jury. Article 39 has "…nisi per legale **judicium** parium suorum", which I believe means "except by the lawful **judgement** of his peers".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *jury,* [Vikipædia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iurata) has **iurata**. That's the root of *jury,* even (via French [*juree*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juree), also in the form of a participle).

I believe its older, primary meaning is "sworn", that is, a group of people who are sworn in.

See also [Du Cange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/IURATA2), which defines *iurata* as "numerus duodecim legalium hominum juratorum, per quos omnis fere facti probatio fit, et ex quorum veredicto judex sententiam suam conficit et profert."

---

For *jury duty,* I think *iurata*'s competing meaning of "sworn" prevents it from serving to make this phrase. Henry Beard offers **officium iudicale**, though perhaps this could also be understood as a "judicial office" in general, as [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=69cPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=vitallarius&source=bl&ots=fvJ9R5-Ycd&sig=mcUm5u4MZ6T1KYRtHI21-WgNTvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5g6ij1q3NAhUXVFIKHRu4DOQQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=vitallarius&f=false) (that has **judicialis** but the same law is quoted elsewhere as **judicalis**—but either way, what's that doing modifying a neuter noun?).

Another approach is to speak of jury "service". I'm not sure, but I think jury "duty" (as a civic obligation) is much less common in countries with a civil-law tradition than in the common-law countries. If so, it might be difficult to find established Latin usage for *jury duty.* Spanish has *servicio de jurado,* as in [this Seattle brochure](http://www.seattle.gov/courts/docs/spanish/JuryBrochureSpanish.pdf) for jurors. I don't think we can roll that back to Latin, though, since **servitium iudicale** would mean "judicial servitude". (Well, I suppose you could say that if you wanted to describe jury duty quite disparagingly.)

Well, I'm going with **officium iudicale**.

Comment: Thank you! I generally find *Vikipædia* untrustworthy, but from http://www.wyomingcatholiccollege.com/faculty-pages/patrick-owens/lexicon/adumbratio/index.aspx I see that "jury selection" is *júrátórum éléctió*.

Comment: About your edit—what difficulty do you see in Du Cange's *juratorum electio* (from the noun *jurator, juratoris*)?

Comment: Unless it's from *juratus*, which maybe makes more sense.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Maybe I'm answering a different question than you meant to ask. I understand _juratorum electio_ to mean the process of choosing the jurors (and it sounds pretty good to me!). I was trying to translate "jury duty", which can be understood two ways in English: (1) the obligation of citizens to serve on juries; (2) the service performed by jurors. Jury selection is something you're involved with as a juror, but it's not equivalent to jury duty. Did I misunderstand your question (or your comment)?

Comment: Ah! I think we have slightly different understandings of the term. When I said "I have jury duty today" I meant that I went down to the courthouse to be a member of the pool of potential jurors, from among whom several juries would be selected. I wasn't chosen. I suppose that if I had been, I'd say "I'm serving on a jury" rather than "I'm on jury duty."

Comment: @JoelDerfner Interesting. I've never seen "jury duty" used to mean only the selection process, but I just looked at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jury_duty) and it gives _only_ that meaning! That strikes me as weird usage, since it excludes actually serving on a jury. [Books](https://www.google.com/#q=%22jury+duty%22&tbm=bks) and laws, AFAIK, mean by "jury duty" serving as a juror, the selection process being only the first step. But, clearly you're not alone. Maybe this is the result of most people's experience: not getting selected, so "jury duty" = waiting in the pool. :)

Comment: Well, most people are called upon to show up and not called upon to serve. That's the duty I have in mind. (Am on phone so terse.)